# How to catch data send via extjs's store.sync() method

Tags: extjs, yii, synchronization

i am working in extjs+Yii. My client side functionality is desighned in yii and server side functionality is in extjs. In extjs controller i had written code to send dynamically generate store,set its proxy and using sync() method of store.

```
 review:function()
    {  var reviewQuestionStore=Ext.create('Balaee.store.qb.QbqnsStore');
        proxy=reviewQuestionStore.getProxy();
        Ext.apply(proxy.api,{
            read:'http://127.0.0.1/s_balaee/Balaee/index.php/QuestionBank/Qbpaper/ReviewQuestionPaper',
            create:'http://127.0.0.1/s_balaee/Balaee/index.php/QuestionBank/Qbpaper/ReviewQuestionPaper',
        });
        Ext.apply(proxy.writer,{
            type:'json',
            root:'records'
        });

        Ext.apply(proxy.reader,{
            type:'json',
            root:'questions'
        });
        var getdata=this.getLocalvalue();
            UserId=getdata.data.userId;

        //Using sync method
        var check =Ext.create('Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsModel',{
                    questionPaperNo:Paperno,
                    userId: UserId,
                });
        reviewQuestionStore.add(check);
        reviewQuestionStore.sync();  
}
```

So its working corectly. And its sending data in json format as-

```
{"records":{"userId":"5","firstName":"abc","middleName":"","lastName":"","languageId":"","primaryEmail":"sdf@sdf.dfg","birthDate":"","password":"","securityQuestionId":"","securityQuestionAnswer":"","isMale":"","creationTime":"","ipAddress":"","confirmationCode":"","userStatusId":"","question":"","id":null}}
```

Now i want to catch this data in yii controller function.  i had tried as-

```
 $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
      $clientData = $postData['records'];
```

and to access fields i am using $clientData['firstName'].But its not working.So how to catch data in Yii which is send via Extjs's store sync() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Standard Yii Json decode.It will create array for you

```
$data=  CJSON::decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```